# How to pass javascript/jQuery settings from page to page in rails?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

When doing javascript manipulation of what's visible, how does one pass that from page to page (ideally in Rails)?

For example, let's say I have the following simple jQuery code:

```
<% link_to "Next Page", report_path %>
<div class="clickable-div" style="background-color:#FFFFFF;"></div>
<script>
$('.clickable-div').click(function () {
  var color = $(this).css("background-color", "#000000");
});
</script>
```

If it's not clear, the code is just supposed to change the color of the div based on whether or not it has been clicked. Regardless, there's also a link on the page that allows someone to go to the reporting page. What's a way to pass the state of the div to the action call?

**EDIT**

It seems unnecessary to do it in a session - am I wrong? This is just something from one page to the next, I couldn't care less anywhere else on the site.

**EDIT 2**

To confirm, *Rails* needs to have access to the action that occurred in Javascript on the previous page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your persistent storage options are [session](http://www.quarkruby.com/2007/10/21/sessions-and-cookies-in-ruby-on-rails), database (i.e. a preferences table), and cookie.

Comment: I really don't like the idea of doing it in a session - there are lots of these pages on the site, and it seems crazy to store it for the length of a session when it only matters from one page to the next page. I'm never going to use that info afterwards.

Comment: "...it only matters from one page to the next page. I'm never going to use that info afterwards"  This sounds like the entire point of session parameters to me.

Answer (score 2):

Try passing the params through a hidden field - http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-hidden_field

Comment: That will only work if he is submitting the form so the hidden field value would be posted to the server. But if he is just going to another page by clicking the link (which is the case here), hidden field won't help.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use session or cookie, the only other option I see is modify the link URL when that div color changes to add a query string parameter with that color.

Comment: I think this may be the way... i 'll try it and come back.

Comment: It's pretty much the only way if you are just going to another page by using a link (that's if you don't want cookies involved). But you could still use a short lived cookie - set it to background color here and then check for it on the reporting page - if cookie exists, get the color and kill the cookie. Just an idea...

Answer (score 0):

There is no need if *jQuery* or *Javascript*.

Onto the call of that link you can either store background-color in **SESSION** or **COOKIE**

Comment: see comment on dorkitude. isn't using a session overkill?

Comment: further, this doesn't seem to meet the need of storing the javascript action in a way that rails can process it.